# How to move a div to a certain position on the page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the red div to come up and sit under the click me link when that link is clicked.

```
$('.clickMe').click(function() {

    var pos = $(this).offset().top;           

    $('.myDiv').animate({
        marginTop: '-'+pos+'px',
    }, 1000 );       

});
```

```
<a href="" class="clickMe">Click Me</a>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div style="position: absolute; border: 1px solid red; height: 50px; width: 50px" class="myDiv"></div>
```

Here's my failed attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/SWqmb/4/

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead, animating the `top` property is probably a better choice, negative margins can have undesirable effects:

```
$('.clickMe').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var pos = $(this).offset().top;           

    $('.myDiv').animate({
        top: pos + $(this).height()
    }, 1000 );

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SWqmb/6/

Comment: I notice this does not work well when you give the `<a>` a lot of padding, can anyone solve it? Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SWqmb/11/ - Setting margin or height still works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. http://jsfiddle.net/SWqmb/8/

But i think is not the best way to do it.